# Can PHP's sleep() function eventually lead to a timeout in the browser?

Tags: php, networking

I've been thinking about uses for php's `sleep()` function, and was wondering exactly how it works over the HTTP protocol.

From a user's perspective (and what I've observed), when `sleep()` is executed, the browser hangs until the delay is finished.

**My question:** What if you were to call sleep for time long enough that the browser doesn't get a response and thinks the server is out? Is this a thing that can happen?

I have little knowledge on this function and how it works, so if somebody could point me in the right direction then that would be amazing.

(By the word timeout, I'm not talking about PHP's max_execution_time. I'm talking about browser timeout.)

Comment: it would be so easy for you to just test this

Comment: @tim It seems pretty obvious that I can do that, but I'm asking this on SO because I would also like an explanation as to why the answer is why it is.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, or is there a problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: @DaveS Mostly curiosity. I want to know more about how the function works to see if I can put it to good use.

Comment: The function just makes the PHP script stop for that amount of time. As far as the browser is concerned, it's no different from a script that's doing a real slow SQL query, or calcuating a million digits of π. If the browser has a timeout for a slow server, it will occur.

Comment: In other words, the browser doesn't know why the script takes a long time to finish. There's nothing special about `sleep()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, each browser has its own default time out limit. For chrome, it is 300 seconds. [Check this out for more details.](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/net/socket/client_socket_pool.cc?sq=package:chromium&l=28)

For chrome, it is not changeable. In Firefox, you can change it, though.

So eventually, if you `sleep()` your script for a number of seconds higher than the browser's out-of-the-box default timeout limit, it is just gonna time out.

Reason? Simply browser doesn't like keep-alive connections that much and wants to hear an answer from the server at a reasonable time frame.